# API Gateway Integration with Lambda and DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've been trying to send a REST API call to trigger Lambda to query into a table in DynamoDB.
I put in the snippet below for my API mapping template

```
**{
    "TableName": "Metadata",
    "PrimaryKey": "ID",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "ID = :v1",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues" : {
        ":v1": {
            "S": "$input.params('ID')"
        }
    }
}**
```

I don't know what I should put in my lambda function for it to grab the ID parameter from the API call. So far, I have

```
**import boto3
import json
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('Metadata')
def lambda_handler(event,context):
    mdID = event['params']['queryString']['ID']
    response = table.getItem(
        key = {
            'ID': mdID
        }
    )
    
    return response**
```

Can you please tell me what I can put instead of "event['params']['queryString']['ID']"?
Thank you!!

Comment: Depends on if you're using path parameters or the body for sending the id.

Comment: I am sending the id with my api call when I curl the deployed api endpoint

Comment: Yes I got that, so you are using a GET Request right? What path parameter did you specify when you created your Gateway?